# MySQL UPDATE множественный инкремент в зависимости от условия

Tags: mysql, sql, update, дерево

Доброго дня.

Вот MySQL-[полигон](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8af7ca/1) с примерной по структуре таблицей.

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (id INT, for_id INT, lvl INT, name VARCHAR(90), quant INT);
```

```js
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES(1, 0, 0, 'bob', 0),
  (2, 0, 0, 'fred', 0),
  (4, 1, 1, 'joe', 0),
  (5, 1, 1, 'mack', 0),
  (6, 5, 2, 'bill', 0),
  (7, 5, 2, 'rex', 0),
  (8, 3, 2, 'tom', 0),
  (9, 7, 3, 'ted', 0);
```

Это "товарные категории". При добавлении товара в поле `quant` делаем инкремент, то есть количество товара в данной категории.

Но затруднение вызывает необходимость обновлять значение этого поля в родительских категориях, если `level` ! = 0

[Например](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8af7ca/1), добавлен товар в категорию `ted`, которая является дочерней (см. `for_id=7`) для категории `rex`, которая, в свою очередь, является дочерней для категории `mack` с `id=5`.

И у всех них нужно "заинкрементить" поле `quant`.

Возможно ли реализовать это одним запросом, и если да, то как?

Спасибо!

Comment: *Возможно ли реализовать это одним запросом* Запросом - нет. У MySQL нет ни рекурсивных запросов, ни каскадности триггеров. Подобную логику следует организовывать в рамках ХП. Но больше всего непонятно,зачем надо статически хранить счётную характеристику...

Comment: Да требует жена, чтобы возле категорий отображалось и количество товара в ней. Ну, как здесь: https://www.livemaster.ru/

Comment: Ну так получайте это количество запросом. Хранить-то зачем? Случись опять же где косяк со значением - ни в жисть не найдёте... А заодно, раз уж храните дерево, и требуются подобные операции, лишний раз подумайте о том, в каком формате хранить...

Comment: Да это же сколько нужно будет делать запросов с SUM(*) на каждой странице?! Это ж кошмар!!

Comment: При правильной структуре хранения - один.

Comment: Категорий много. И они редактируемы. Поэтому для них была создана отдельная таблица. Как и здесь https://www.livemaster.ru/, они выводятся с раскрытием подкатегорий, и у каждой должно отображатьбся количество товара. И что-то мне подскзывает, что можно все это сделать в рамках одного запроса к таблице категорий.

Comment: @Akina вариант, что хранить счетную характеристику, чтобы не считать ее в принципе постоянно, а только периодически пересчитывать, уже не вариант что ли? :)

Comment: @Akina "_Запросом - нет_". Почему нет ? Запросом можно сделать все. (по крайней мере до тех пор, пока изменения надо внести только в одну таблицу)

Comment: @Mike потому что не все настолько хорошо знают SQL, как вы.

Comment: @Alex78191 Так я это только к тому, что никогда не надо быть слишком категоричным с "это невозможно", большинство людей читая, что, что то невозможно опускают руки и решение не находят только потому, что не пытаются

Comment: @Mike Ну не документирован порядок вычисления переменных. Да, твой запрос работает правильно, и скорее всего во всей линейке версий 5.х так и будет... но чтобы убедиться, что всё это "от лукавого", достаточно поменять местами поля выходного набора подзапроса: `select @id:=(select for_id from table_name where id=@id), @id id` - первая в дереве запись тут же выпадет из обновления.

Comment: @Akina Ну если они изменят этот порядок 80% запросов с переменными перестанет работать. И в следующей ветке скорее всего это будет не нужно, `with recursive` уже есть в текущих экспериментальных версиях, думаю до следующей ветки то обкатают. И при желании первую запись можно union получить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Увеличение количества для всех категорий в дереве начиная с заданной ('ted'):

```
update table_name T
  join (
        select @id id,@id:=(select for_id from table_name where id=@id)
          from table_name,
               (select @id:=id from table_name where name='ted') init
          limit 10
       ) O
     on O.id=T.id
    set quant=quant+1
```

Пример на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19350c/1)

Число 10 в limit надо заменить на максимальный уровень вложенности категорий в вашей БД с некоторым запасом. Данное ограничение несколько ускоряет запрос, позволяя не делать лишние попытки углубится в иерархию.

P.S. Вообще работа с деревьями в MySQL довольно тяжела и всегда приходится прибегать к подобной магии с переменными. Настоятельно рекомендуется работать с такими структурами данных в других СУБД, поддерживающих рекурсивные запросы "из коробки", например PostgreSQL.

Comment: Спасибо, Майк! Потрясающе! Такая лаконичность, что...