# Table 's' is specified twice

Tags: mysql

Пишем запрос следующий:

```
update shus 
set s.delta = -687       
where s.material_id = 230   
AND s.recount_id = 1989 
and s.updated_at in (
    select max(s2.updated_at) 
    from shus s2 
    where s2.material_id = 230  
    AND s2.recount_id = 1989
    );
```

Выдается ошибка

> Table 's' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a
>   separate source for data

Comment: В MySQL нельзя в IN использовать ту же таблицу, которая изменяется. ее можно указывать только в части join. Примерно как тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/731732/194569

Comment: не вижу, где вообще определен алиас `s`

Comment: Спасибо,да это фича SQL с которой не встречался ранее

Answer (score 0):

Надо сделать так:

```
update shus s set s.delta = -687       where s.material_id = 
230   AND s.recount_id = 1989 and Exists (
select topdate from (select max(s2.updated_at) as topdate from 
shus s2 where s2.material_id = 230  AND s2.recount_id = 1989 
AND s.updated_at = max(s2.updated_at) )     
);
```