# Как обновить часть таблицы за один запрос?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

есть таблица игроков:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть таблица рейтинга:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне необходимо добавлять золото в поле player_gold согласно рейтингу из поля rating_quest_0.

Мой запрос:

```
SET @a:=51;
UPDATE resources_players 
  SET player_gold = player_gold + @a:=@a-1 
  WHERE player_id IN ( SELECT player_id 
                       FROM resources_quests 
                       ORDER BY rating_quest_0 DESC ) LIMIT 50;
```

для связи использую id игроков.
Произвожу сортировку по полю рейтинга, и беру id шники подзапросом в in.
После чего присваиваю золото (первому в рейтинге 50, далее 49 и так далее).

Все работает отлично, но проблема в том что оператор in содержит сразу все id (в порядке присваивания) Но запрос начинает выполняться не в том порядке, в котором я хочу а применяет к той строке, которую первую нашел в in.

Как можно решить эту задачу 1 запросом. Не хотелось бы через цикл делать 50 запросов. Спасибо!

Comment: Сделайте запрос select, который вам вернет 2 поля player_id и вот это значение, которое в `@a` (т.е. тот же счетчик там сделайте). Потом перепишите ваш update так, что бы в нем не было IN а был JOIN с подзапросом, который вы перед этим подготовили.

Comment: Т.е. что то в этом роде https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/731732/194569 только запрос внутри скобок гораздо проще

Comment: *присваиваю золото (первому в рейтинге 50, далее 49 и так далее)* Щазз! Сортировка в подзапросе - игнорируется. LIMIT в запросе - обновляет случайные 50 записей в случайном порядке.

Comment: @Mike Спасибо! Решил задачу таким запросом: 
`SET @a:=51;

UPDATE resources_players rp INNER JOIN (SELECT player_id FROM resources_quests WHERE rating_quest_0 != 0 ORDER BY rating_quest_0 DESC LIMIT 50) rq SET player_gold = player_gold + @a:=@a-1 WHERE rp.player_id = rq.player_id;`

Comment: я бы номер считал все таки в подзапросе, что то вроде`UPDATE resources_players rp INNER JOIN (SELECT player_id, @a:=@a-1 add_num FROM resources_quests WHERE rating_quest_0 != 0 ORDER BY rating_quest_0 DESC LIMIT 50) rq SET player_gold = player_gold + add_num WHERE rp.player_id = rq.player_id;` так надежнее. что бы номер получался именно там где задан order by

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @a:=51;

UPDATE resources_players rp INNER JOIN (SELECT player_id FROM resources_quests WHERE rating_quest_0 != 0 ORDER BY rating_quest_0 DESC LIMIT 50) rq SET player_gold = player_gold + @a:=@a-1 WHERE rp.player_id = rq.player_id;
```